# XCode lost ability to syntax highlight

Tags: ios, xcode, macos, swift

I'm using Swift. This happens all the time, usually a clean and build, or sometimes switching files, or sometimes quitting xcode will help. None of those things are working this time, and it's been ongoing for hours. I've tried:

- Switching files
- Cleaning project
- Cleaning build folder
- Deleting derived data
- Quitting Xcode
- Restarting my computer

Nothing seems to get it to syntax highlight, or reasonably suggest code. It means I can't click on anything, I can't use autocomplete, and I can't get suggestions. But it does allow me to build and run, and shows errors when I have them, after I build.

I'm not sure what's wrong - i don't believe anything in my project changed structurally, yet this is rendering me incapable of working today.

Comment: Are you using a virtual machine like VMware? If you do, try changing its settings. What happens if you restart the virtual machine or operating system? Does it solve the problem? Have you enter menu Xcode, option Preferences?

Comment: Nope, no virtual machine.

Comment: Is everything related to Code Completion still selected when you go into settings?

Comment: "XCode lost ability …", "I'm using Swift." – Nuff said.

Comment: I had something odd happen one day that may be related. It wasn't syntax highlighting but modules that refused to build properly. The reason I bring it up is that inside the ~/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData folder is a ModuleCache folder that does not appear to ever get cleaned by the standard methods. It may be a red-herring, but it's something that's not touched by your other efforts.

Comment: Which version of Xcode are you having issues with? Are you still having this issue? Have you upgraded to the latest version?

Comment: You should use stable version of Xcode (6.2). Alternatively, re-installing xCode might fix problem.

Answer (score 2):

This usually happens, unfortunately...

Just clean all folders (or just with your project name) inside `/Users/'you'/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData`, and everything back to normal.

Edit: Emphasizing line above!!!

**Look at your code, something crashing this functionality.**

This happened to me, just changed one particular block of code, and then everything back to normal, of course, after clean DerivedData folder too.

Comment: it worked for me. cannot understand why it was down voted.